# O que fazer quando um usuario com muita reputação faça uma pergunta que ele mesmo sabe a resposta

Tags: debate

Não sei se fui claro, mais percebo que alguns usuário com muito reputação fazem perguntas repetidas e meramente facéis de se encontrar respostas, apenas para obter mais visitas e reputações. Por exemplo: "O que é Lógica de Programação?", eu não vou falar qual usuário mais este tem mais de 15 mil de reputação. Não queria ofender ninguém com a pergunta, mais qual a opinião de vocês?

Comment: Creio que seja uma duplicada: [Questão simples demais feita por um “experiente”](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2170/3117)

Comment: Aproveitar o conhecimento :)

Comment: Desculpe eu entendo uma parte da sua pergunta, mas acusar não acho correto, talvez o motivo seja agregar conteudo, o proprio sistema do site permite nós mesmos respondermos no mesmo momento que perguntamos. Recomendo que poste o link da postagem, não se preocupe aqui no meta é para resolver este tipo de situação mesmo :)

Comment: Digamos que um usuário tenha conquistado 15mil de reputação por responder sempre C#, e esta agora aprendendo Python, ele não poderia fazer perguntas "simples" sobre um matéria nova?

Comment: Já sei que não sou eu, só tenho 13k :p

Comment: Deve ser eu, tudo o que as pessoas acham que está errado, eu é que sou o culpado :D Tô só zuando... não levem a sério!

Comment: De qualquer maneira, acho legal você perguntar isto, pois muitos saem distribuindo negativos porque "acham errado" alguma coisa, sendo que na verdade pode ser algo comum de alguma comunidade especifica. Acho muito bom sempre perguntar primeiro ao invés de ficar no "achismo" e sair dando downvotes de graça +1 para pergunta, o meta é pra isto mesmo, tirar duvidas :)

Comment: Não só *downvotes*, ter outras atitudes também. Não entendo como algumas pessoas mais novas no site não percebem que os que tem grande reputação sabem o que estão fazendo. Eles não chegaram ali fazendo um monte de coisa errada. Por isso realmente é muito bom procurar se informar sobre como as coisas funcionam.

Comment: @bigown Bem colocado, infelizmente muitos querem chegar bancando os donos da verdade e querendo fazer a suas maneiras trazendo vicios de fóruns, comunidades do face e das comunidades do falecido orkut.

Comment: Tem uns dias de chuva, sem nada pra fazer, nenhuma pergunta legal pra responder, que sei lá... o pessoal procura algo útil pra passar o tempo :) PS: fiz aquela pergunta sobre o console.log quando estava com um problema e pesquisando sobre o assunto, talvez pudesse ter aprofundado mais na hora de perguntar...

Comment: Acho que tudo é questão de como se enxerga as coisas, questões simples podem ser super úteis para milhares de pessoas(mesmo que não seja para quem a criou), o problema é se a pergunta é inútil, mal formulada e que não da para chegar a nenhuma resposta por simplesmente não ser clara o suficiente, ai ela não ajuda ninguém. Se um usuário experiente consegue criar uma pergunta boa, mesmo que simples, e ganhar reputação com isso, ele ganha, a comunidade ganha, e isso é ótimo!

Comment: A minha pergunta seria uma dúvida mesmo sabe. Entendo que alguns sacam muito de C# e nas outras coisas não sabem nada, mais tenho um colega aqui com muita reputação que faz a pergunta que ele mesmo sabe a resposta e convenhamos já existia a mesma dúvida no SO. Estou aqui para aprender também e não para ganhar reputação, isso é consequencia de uma boa resposta :D

Comment: Não tem importância se a pergunta já existe no SO (em inglês), se ela não existe aqui (em português) muita gente ainda fica sem acesso ao conteúdo, porque não entende inglês. A reputação faz parte do jogo do site, é uma das maneiras de atrair participantes. Você tem todo o direito de não ligar pra isso, é uma das maneiras de se usar o site. Mas quem entra no jogo atrás de reputação não está errado, os pontos existem para serem conquistados, e o jogo é um estímulo à participação. O que não vale é abuso de votos, que já é outra história.